# Editing assets custom fields in a full page publish form

Tags: assets

So this is just a question to see if something is actually doable.

When you double click an asset, you get a little modal opening where you can see see custom field attached to said asset.

Would it be possible (plugin work I'm guessing) to open this model as a full publish form like entries have..?

Just wondering... :)

Comment: You mean from the assets tab, not from an entry's assets field, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this should be possible from a plugin. But you could also suggest this as a new core feature on the [Craft Feedback](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com) page. I'd definitly vote for this! ;)

Comment: I thought it would be a plugin Job.

Thank you for your answer though and I will post that as a request for sure :)

Comment: Don't forget to update your question with the link to the feature request, to receive some attention ;)